# Help to ID military Space Opera trilogy with feliniods (tigerish) and suspended animation using a gas

Tags: story-identification, military-sf

I read this trilogy in the 90's, though it might be older. There is a felinoid security officer on the starship who goes EVA from one hatch to another in an effort to prove that it was possible for an opposing infiltrator/saboteur/assassin to do so.

The very much disliked hard horse captain of the ship has a partial brain augmentation (I believe to repair damage). I don't remember how, but the opposing force managed to place get him into a chamber filled with the gas used in suspended animation without the prerequisite drugging and preparation leaving the crew wondering if the man was actually dead or if his implant had absorbed enough of his personality to make it appear as though he were still alive.

Comment: What does "hard horse" mean?  Is the captain some form of equinoid?

Comment: @DavidW "sailors' term for a tyrannical officer"

Comment: Hi Otis, the questioned book wasn't right, but the answer by @LSerni was spot on, as was the answer (below)! Thanks!

Comment: see OP confirmation comment above

Comment: Note that the answer to _this_ question is the trilogy starting from *Voyage of the Star Wolf* while the answer to the previous question was just *Starhunt* / *Yesterday's Children* and not the following trilogy.

Answer (score 7):

[*Star Wolf* series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?12243) by David Gerrold

It's a while since I've read them but I do remember the security officer who was fighting on the side of the humans against his own people, and the commanding officer with the implant.

The trilogy followed on from a standalone novel [*Starhunt*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?18176) which used some of the same characters and situations

- [*Yesterday's Children*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?770) (1972), revised as [*Starhunt*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?18176) (1985)
- [*Voyage of the Star Wolf*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?458) (1990)
- [*The Middle of Nowhere*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9479) (1995)
- [*Blood and Fire*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?153558) (2004)

Comment: You don't mention whether any of the characters appeared to be "tigerish" (or evolved from any type of feline creature). If that was definitely the case, then mentioning it would bolster your assertion that this is the series Ring had in mind.

Comment: In the series, the security officer is a "Morthan", who resemble tigers. He does attempt to do a timed EVA from one airlock to another to prove that an enemy Morthan could have done the same.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. That is exactly the series I'm looking for. I gave away my library several years ago and now have mixed feelings about not having those thousands of books at hand.